# Async/Await inside reducer in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    value: {
      fields: initialState,
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    loginUser: async (state, action) => {
      state.value.fields.loading = true;
      await http
        .post("/login", {
          email: state.value.fields.email,
          password: state.value.fields.password,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
        });
    },
  },
});
```

I'm receiving an error saying `A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path:` auth`. Value:` When I try to make this `loginUser` async.When I remove `async` `await` from the `loginUser` it's working.Really appreciate it if somebody could help.

Comment: when you ```await``` a promise the fulfilled result will return and don't need ```then```. Also when you are using ```redux``` you need to use ```redux-thunk``` or ```redux-saga``` to achieve async operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You must *never* do *any* async work inside of a Redux reducer!**

One of the primary rules of Redux is:

> Reducers *must always* be 100% synchronous and "pure", with no side effects ( https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects )

Additionally, *all* state updates must be done by "dispatching an action" (like `store.dispatch({type: "todos/todoAdded", payload: "Buy milk"})` ), and then letting the reducer look at that action to decide what the new state should be.

If you need to do async work, the right answer is usually to [put the async logic into a "thunk", and dispatch actions based on the async results](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic).

I'd strongly recommend going through the Redux docs tutorials to learn more about this and how to use Redux:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index